# CSS hover for after and before background images

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

when you hover over the image blue arrow moves slowly. When you remove the cursor from the image white arrow comes back sharply. How to make a white arrow return slowly?

```css
@keyframes left_to_right {
    from {margin-left: -15px;}
    to {margin-left: 0; }
}
div .footer-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 3%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 85%;
}
div .footer-text:after{
    content: '';
    background: url('https://www.nsartmuseum.ru/images/test/arrow-after-3.png') no-repeat;
    width: 130px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
div:hover .footer-text:before{
    content: '';
    background: url('https://www.nsartmuseum.ru/images/test/arrow-before-3.png') no-repeat;
    width: 130px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: left_to_right 0.4s ease;
}
div:hover .footer-text:after{
    content: '';
    background: none;
}
div .footer-text span{
    position: relative;
    top:-5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #313B78;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="" class='footer-text'>
  <span>13 September</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Obviously, there are ways to do this by CSS animation, but I've never used this in my development.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required to use `animation` for that. `transition` is enough 
just add `transition: width .4s ease;` to `:after` for unhovered element and play with `width` attribute

```css
div .footer-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 3%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 85%;
}

div .footer-text span{
    position: relative;
    top:-5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #313B78;
    display: inline-block;
}

div .footer-text:after{
    content: '';
    background: url('https://www.nsartmuseum.ru/images/test/arrow-after-3.png') no-repeat right;
    width: 130px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    transition: width .4s ease;
}

div:hover .footer-text:after{
    width: 0;
}

div .footer-text:before{
    content: '';
    background: url('https://www.nsartmuseum.ru/images/test/arrow-before-3.png') no-repeat right;
    width: 0;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: width .4s ease;
}
div:hover .footer-text:before{
    width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="" class='footer-text'>
  <span>13 September</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes left_to_right {
  from {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

div .footer-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 3%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 85%;
}

div .footer-text:after {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://www.nsartmuseum.ru/images/test/arrow-after-3.png') no-repeat;
  width: 130px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  animation: left_to_right 0.4s ease;
}

div:hover .footer-text:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://www.nsartmuseum.ru/images/test/arrow-before-3.png') no-repeat;
  width: 130px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: left_to_right 0.4s ease;
}

div:hover .footer-text:after {
  display: none;
}

div .footer-text span {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #313B78;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="" class='footer-text'>
    <span>13 September</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it:)

```css
div {
  width:50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
div .footer-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div .footer-text:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%228%22%20height%3D%2215%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%208%2015%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M1%201.5l6%206-6%206%22%20stroke%3D%22%23C5C8D0%22%20stroke-width%3D%221.2%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') no-repeat right center;
  background-size: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-7px);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

div .footer-text span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #313B78;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
div .footer-text span:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin: -7px 20px 0 0;
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%221110%22%20height%3D%2214%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%201110%2014%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23313B78%22%20d%3D%22M1109.424%206.076l-6-6a.599.599%200%2010-.848.848l4.975%204.976H1a.6.6%200%20100%201.2h1106.551l-4.975%204.976a.599.599%200%2010.848.848l6-6a.6.6%200%20000-.848z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') no-repeat right top;
    background-size: auto 14px;
}
div .footer-text span:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background: #C5C8D0;
    left: calc(100% + 20px);
}
div .footer-text:hover:before {
    transform: translate(20px,-7px);
}
div .footer-text:hover span {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="" class='footer-text'>
  <span>13 September</span>
</a>
</div>
```